# how to make WP7 maps to fill the entire viewing page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="Images/map_bg.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <my:Map Height="649" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="451" LogoVisibility="Collapsed"  Margin="2,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
```

i tried to play abit with the Height and Width variables but that only changed the position of the map rather than stretching the entire maps.

is it possible at all to make the map to 'fill' the entire  `<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">` property?
thanks!

edit

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Opacity="0.7">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"></StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Image Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="Images/map_bg.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <my:Map Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="451" LogoVisibility="Collapsed"  CredentialsProvider="xxx" Margin="2,0,0,0" Height="645" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Just to confirm : you're not trying to zoom the map, just have the control fill the available space?

Answer (score 2):

I removed all margins/size/positioning elements in my map control to let it expand itself.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <my:Map CredentialsProvider="abcdefg"  Name="map1"   >
        <my:MapLayer Name="mapLayer"/>
    </my:Map>
</Grid>
```

Comment: try opening your project in blend and looking at all the different container elements. Something has to be restricting the size.

Comment: did you resolve this yet? Where is your map failing to fill the page? T/L/R/B? Your map should have space above for the other elements on your page as you have it defined.

Comment: One thing I did notice that appears odd is you're defining your image in the second row have have it set to consume two rows `Grid.RowSpan="2"`. Is this working as intended or is it causing these issues with your map?